# Tidying up CSS where classes have the same properties

Tags: css

I have an extremely messy stylesheet that I'm trying to clean up, and one thing I've searched for an answer to is how to clean an example of this up:

```
.element .Change {
  font-size: 1em;
}

.element .Name {
  font-size: 1em;
}
```

can this be re-written in a cleaner way?  ex:

```
.element .Change, .Name {
  font-size: 1em;
}
```

I should probably know this, but when I search for putting CSS on one line, I get examples of single-line CSS.

Thanks for your help

Comment: I got what looked like a "period" (not quite a period, was more of a very tiny square) showing up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, almost exactly as you propose.

```
.element .Change,
.element .Name {
  font-size: 1em;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.element .Change, .element .Name {
  font-size: 1em;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

CSS redundancy is not all the bad, as you need to keep some buffer for future changes.

If you're sure that your styling won't change, then what you have done is perfectly fine.

I'd advise you to have a look at [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) and other similar compile-to-CSS languages.

Comment: Thanks @badZoke - I just discovered LESS while adding tags to this post.  I had heard about it before, but didn't know it would suit me.  I'll take a look at it, thanks again.